# How do I create tabView through @PostConstructor

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working on JSF 2.1 and PrimeFaces 5.0 and I am trying to create `TabView` from  `@PostConstructor` but not able to make it happen.Is it possible to make tab view like this.

`@PostConstructor` but not able to make it happen properly.

XHTML source :

```
<div align="center">
    <h1 style="margin-top:0;   color: cornflowerblue">Basic User Form</h1>
</div>

<h:form id="initTest"  >
    <p:tabView  binding="#{initTestMgBean.tabView}"/>
</h:form>
```

ManagedBean Source :

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class initTestMgBean {

    private TabView tabView;

    public TabView getTabView() {
        return tabView;
    }

    public void setTabView(TabView tabView) {
        this.tabView = tabView;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        tabView = new TabView();
        tabView.setInView(true);

        Tab tab1 = new Tab();
        tab1.setTitle("User Form 1");


        Tab tab2 = new Tab();
        tab2.setTitle("User Form 2");

        tabView.getChildren().add(tab1);
        tabView.getChildren().add(tab2);

        PanelGrid panel1 = new PanelGrid();
        panel1.setId("panel1");
        panel1.setColumns(2);

        PanelGrid panel2 = new PanelGrid();
        panel2.setId("panel2");
        panel2.setColumns(2);

        HtmlOutputLabel label = new HtmlOutputLabel();
        label.setId("outlab");
        label.setValue("Name ");
        label.setFor("name");

        InputText text = new InputText();
        text.setId("name");
        text.setSize(15);
        text.setStyle("height:30px");

        HtmlOutputLabel label4 = new HtmlOutputLabel();
        label4.setId("outlab4");
        label4.setFor("userName");
        label4.setValue("User Name");

        InputText text4 = new InputText();
        text4.setId("userName");
        text4.setSize(15);
        text4.setStyle("height:30px");

        tab1.getChildren().add(panel1);

        panel1.getChildren().add(label);
        panel1.getChildren().add(text);

        tab2.getChildren().add(panel2);
        panel2.getChildren().add(label4);
        panel2.getChildren().add(text4);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried injecting it instead? Try this and see if it works:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class TabViewBean implements Serializable {

    private TabView tabView;

    public TabViewBean(){ }

    @Inject
    public TabViewBean(SomeOtherBean unused){

        tabView = new TabView();

        Tab tab = new Tab();
        tab.setTitle("I'm a title");            
        tabView.getChildren().add(tab);

        //Tab tab2 = new Tab();
        //tab2.setTitle(unused.getTitle());
        //tabView.getChildren().add(tab2);

    }

    public TabView getTabView(){
        return tabView;
    }

    public void setTabView(TabView tabView){
        this.tabView = tabView;
    }

}
```

I've included another bean just as an example how to access other beans when injecting. You don't have to use it.

Comment: Not able to achieve it can you give some more idea about injecting or how i implement it.. Thanx for reply

Comment: Read from Oracle here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/cdi-javaee-bien-225152.html or a more specific tutorial here: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/java-ee-cdi-dependency-injection-inject-tutorial.html

Comment: You are welcome, please tell me if it works. Maybe others have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

By This way we able to add tabView Dynamically over Xhtml

```
 @ManagedBean  
@SessionScoped  

public class TabViewBean implements Serializable {

    public TabViewBean() {
            fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            tabView = (TabView) fc.getApplication().createComponent(
                    "org.primefaces.component.TabView");
            Tab tab1 = new Tab();
            tab1.setTitle("User Form 1");
            Tab tab2 = new Tab();
            tab2.setTitle("User Form 2");

            tabView.getChildren().add(tab1);
            tabView.getChildren().add(tab2);

            tabView.setActiveIndex(0);
        }

    public TabView getTabView() {
        return tabView;
    }

    public void setTabView(TabView tabView) {
        this.tabView = tabView;
    }

    public void addTabs() {
        Tab tab3 = new Tab();
        tab3.setTitle("Manage Favorites");
        tab3.setClosable(true);
        tabView.getChildren().add(tab3);
        System.out.println("Called");
    }

    FacesContext fc;
    TabView tabView;

}
```